# Use bash, how to filter by n chars in `for` cycle

Tags: bash, grep

**Issue**

I need filter files from output by first 12 chars, and send as output to `ffmpeg` command, and then do it again for next cycle.

Input file.

```
VID_20190920_195919.mp4
VID_20190920_200821.mp4
VID_20190920_221640.mp4
VID_20190921_141929.mp4
VID_20190921_142236.mp4
```

Filtered output in 1st cycle (by first 12 chars, so by `VID_20190920`).

```
VID_20190920_195919.mp4
VID_20190920_200821.mp4
VID_20190920_221640.mp4
```

Filtered output in 2nd cycle (by first 12 chars, so by `VID_20190921`).

```
VID_20190921_141929.mp4
VID_20190921_142236.mp4
```

etc.

Every cycle (list of filtered files) has to be export to `cycle.txt`, then file has be processed by this command.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i cycle.txt -c copy VID_YYYYMMRR.mp4
```

Then clean `cycle.txt` by `> cycle.txt` and do it again for next cycle.

Or is the better simpliest way to do that?

Thanks.

**System**

```
Linux local 5.0.0-29-lowlatency #31-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Sep 12 14:13:01 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: The "20" and "21" are fixed or could be any other number?

Comment: @guillermochamorro There is more dates, for example `VID_20190820*`, `VID_20190825*`, etc. So I need `grep` all files with this characters on begin, and write it to file. I tried `cut -c 1-12`, but there is no way to display whole name of file in this case. Or maybe I can use `cut -c 1-12 | sort -n | uniq` on this output and then use `for` fot this output. But is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may do:

```
unique=($(cat foo | cut -c 5-12 | sort -u))

for i in "${!unique[@]}"; do 
  find *${unique[$i]}* > cycle_$i
done
```

---

Create an array with only the dates:

```
unique=($(cat foo | cut -c 5-12 | sort -u))
```

---

Loop through the array and find the files that match each date and save the output into file with an index name:

```
for i in "${!unique[@]}"; do 
  find *${unique[$i]}* > cycle_$i
done
```

---

Result:

cycle_0.txt

```
VID_20190920_195919.mp4
VID_20190920_200821.mp4
VID_20190920_221640.mp4
```

cycle_1.txt

```
VID_20190921_141929.mp4
VID_20190921_142236.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your video files are in the same directory, you can use these bash commands:

```
for i in VID_*.mp4; do
  echo ${i%_*}
done | sort -u | while read f; do
  ffmpeg -f concat -i <(echo ${f}*) -c copy "${f}.mp4"  
done
```

The script gets all videos `VID_*.mp4` and strips out the suffix `_XXX.mp4` from the name.
Then loops through all unique names in the form `VID_XXX` and execute the `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Seems better than 2 `for` loops as I tried, but error `[concat @ 0x555e24bd9940] Line 1: unknown keyword 'VID_20190921_141929.mp4'
/dev/fd/63: Invalid data found when processing input`. Where is the catch? I tried `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(echo ${f}*) -c copy "${f}.mp4"` too.

Comment: @genderbee Does your `ffmpeg` command work if you manually add filenames into your `cycle.txt` ?

Comment: Yes, but it is needed in format `file 'VID_YYYYMMDD*'`. I tried `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(echo "file '${f}*'") -c copy "${f}.mp4"`, but probably I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, this solution works.

```
chars=12
    for file in $(find . -name '*.mp4' -printf "%f\n" | sort -n | cut -c 1-$chars | uniq)
    do
        find . -name '*.mp4' | grep $file | sed "s/^/file '/" | sed "s/$/'/" | sort -n > filein
        ffmpeg -v quiet -safe 0 -f concat -i filein -c copy $file.mp4
    done
```

Seems export to file is needed. Or not?

Info.

`chars`, number of same characters to join.

You can add `-mindepth -maxdepth` to `find` command, for folder's depth.